# Unit test help in Python

Tags: python, function, unit-testing

I'm new to coding and trying to test some functions I've made for a simple ATM program.

```
def pin_validation(pin):
    if pin == user_pin:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def log_in():
    tries = 0
    while tries < 3:
        pin = input("Enter PIN: ")
        if pin_validation(pin):
            return True
        else:
            print("Incorrect PIN")
            tries += 1
    raise TypeError("Account locked")
    return False

def withdraw_cash():
    while True:
        amount_to_withdraw = int(input("How much would you like withdraw: "))
        if amount_to_withdraw > user_balance:
            raise ValueError("Not enough funds in account")
        else:
            new_balance = user_balance - amount_to_withdraw
            print("New balance is {}".format(new_balance))
            return False
        assert new_balance > 0
```

So far I've got the following for tests:

```
classTestATM(unittest.testcase):
    def test_pin_validation(self):
        test_input = 9876
        test_result = pin_validation(test_input)
        self.assertEqual(test_result, True)
```

How would I write tests for the other functions?

Comment: I would recommend using patching so that you can control what input returns. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html this will let you test the other two. If you still have issues then you can edit your current post with what you have tried and we can try to help with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can patch the inputs within your functions and use side_effect for the test cases with multiple inputs.

```
import unittest                                                                                                                                                                               
import unittest.mock                                                                                                                                                                          

classTestATM(unittest.testcase):
    @unittest.mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=[1000, 1001, 1002])                                                                                                                          
    def test_log_in(self):
        self.assertFalse(log_in())

    @unittest.mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=[500, 1000, 2000, 3000]) 
    def test_withdraw_cash(self):
        self.assertFalse(withdraw_cash())
```